# Bootstrap popover with content from template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, popover

How can I use a knockout template as content in a bootstrap popover?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are looking for.  Here is a sample fiddle that I hope will help:

http://jsfiddle.net/V3nVd/3/

It demonstrates two concepts:

1) Using a Custom Binding to add the desired Popover attributes

2) Using a template to encapsulate the HTML (including custom binding) used to create a button with a popover.

Here are the [options](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) you can send into a Popover.

---

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/V3nVd/7/

Updated fiddle to show pulling html content from a rendered template.  Also note the use of the html option in the popover initialization.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I was looking for. In your jsfiddle, I would like the content of the popover (i.e. 'Content One') be defined in a template. My popover will show details of a person (e.g. name, email,...) that I would like to define in a template.
I forked your jsfiddle showing what I'm trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/V3nVd/4/

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a new fiddle that pulls the content from another element rendered by Knockout.  It's not perfect, but shows the general idea.  As far as I know Knockout templates cannot render to a string (like jsrender) so I've had to render a hidden div and then pull the string from it.  Not ideal as it ends up including the content twice.  Maybe one of the folks that understand the internals of Knockout a little better will chime in with a better idea.

Comment: Agree with you that this is not the ideal solution. But it works and until I find a better answer I'm going to use it this way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but the JSFiddle links above didn't work for me due to a jQuery error ("jQuery.clean is not a function").  Changing the version of Knockout appeared to fixed it:  [jsfiddle.net/V3nVd/54/](http://jsfiddle.net/V3nVd/54/)

Comment: Thanks Pete... I guess there must have been some later changes.  My original fiddle works here: http://jsfiddle.net/V3nVd/56/, and my edit is here: http://jsfiddle.net/V3nVd/57/

Comment: All the fiddle mentioned above are failing with error `disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved`

Answer (score 0):

If i change the text binding to a value binding the value was not rendered, if I select the element with ID with jquery and print her value in console, the value's correct but it's not showed.

```
<center>
  <h2>Popover Demo</h2>
  <div data-bind="template: {name: 'popoverTemplate', foreach: commands}"></div>
</center>

<script type="text/html" id="popoverTemplate">
    <div style="display:none;" data-bind="attr: {'id': $data.command + 'Content'}, template: {name: 'popoverContent', data: $data.content}"></div>    
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-bind='text: $data.command, popover: $data'></a>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="popoverContent">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" data-bind='value: $data.name'></p>
    <p>Email: <b data-bind='text: $data.email'></b></p>
</script>
```

​

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/mounir/V3nVd/15/

Thanks

**Edit:**

Here is a complete working example, I changed the `ko.applyBindings()` to `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` to include the binding context $root and $parent when we would like to associate a button for example to a function in a root viewModel.

```
$(element).click(function() {
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            var thePopover = document.getElementById(attribute.id+"-popover");
            childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModel);
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, thePopover);
        });
```

Take a look @JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mounir/Mv3nP/4/